# protonvpn RuntimeError: Couldn't find acceptable executables for {'xdg-open'}

Tags: software-installation, vpn, xdg-open, bodhi

**EDIT #3**:

After a series of attempts at removing packages, and installing again with/without the virtualenv, I came across various hurdles, which required me doing (with the help of [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213921/python-3-installing-gi-package-with-pip), [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526026/how-to-install-gi-module-for-anaconda-python3))

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge pygobject
$ conda install -c conda-forge gtk3
```

At one point, with some combination of actions and configuration (which I cannot reproduce now), I *seemed* to have overcome the error reported, but I was not able to connect to VPN.
After further attempts I am again at the original point.

**EDIT #2**:

```
$ sudo apt install -y python3-gi python3-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-3.0
[sudo] password for user1:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3-gi is already the newest version (3.36.0-1).
python3-gi-cairo is already the newest version (3.36.0-1).
gir1.2-gtk-3.0 is already the newest version (3.24.20-0ubuntu1.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

**EDIT**:

I followed the answer by GADER.
Now I get

```
$ protonvpn-gui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/bin/protonvpn-gui", line 5, in <module>
    from linux_gui.protonvpn_gui import init
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/linux_gui/protonvpn_gui.py", line 9, in <module>
    import gi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

As evident, the python used is from anaconda (and I hope the update didn't break anything).

I still have to debug the new error.

---

**Initial OP**

I installed `protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.1-1_all.deb`
in Bodhi Linux, kernel 5.13.0-39-generic #44~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP, with

```
$ sudo gdebi protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.1-1_all.deb
```

Note that this was done under a `(base)` virtualenv from anaconda, and this might have caused trouble.

When I try to run `protonvpn` (or `protonvpn-cli` or `protonvpn-gui`), I get

```
$ protonvpn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/protonvpn", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('protonvpn-gui==1.7.0', 'console_scripts', 'protonvpn')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 490, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2854, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2445, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2451, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/protonvpn_gui/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    from protonvpn_nm_lib.api import protonvpn
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/protonvpn_nm_lib/api.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .core.report import BugReport
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/protonvpn_nm_lib/core/report/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .bug import BugReport
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/protonvpn_nm_lib/core/report/bug.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..subprocess_wrapper import subprocess
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/protonvpn_nm_lib/core/subprocess_wrapper.py", line 123, in <module>
    subprocess = SubprocessWrapper() # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/protonvpn_nm_lib/core/subprocess_wrapper.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.__ensure_executables_exist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/protonvpn_nm_lib/core/subprocess_wrapper.py", line 81, in __ensure_executables_exist
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Couldn't find acceptable executables for {'xdg-open'}
(base) [user1@Orion:/mnt/shared_data/Downloads]$
```

But I do have a suitable `xdg-open`

```
$ type xdg-open
xdg-open is /usr/bin/xdg-open
```

unless the problem is with versions.

**How can I solve this?**

I saw other reports of `RuntimeError: Couldn't find acceptable executables for ...`
([source](https://dev1galaxy.org/viewtopic.php?pid=32919), [source](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/protonvpn)).

Comment: `sudo apt install python3-gi`

Comment: @GAD3R - Didn't work... strange

Answer (score 0):

Install it through `pip3`:

```
sudo apt install -y python3-gi python3-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-3.0
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install protonvpn-gui
protonvpn-gui
```

Comment: Please see EDIT.

Comment: There might be some ""interference with anaconda. 
See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71869044/protonvpn-runtimeerror-couldnt-find-acceptable-executables-for-xdg-open).